# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

I'm trying to go from EntityFramework v5 to v6 and I'm doing all the necessary changes. But I'm receiving the following error :

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

On

```
public static void RegisterAuth()
{
   WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);                                  
}
```

I figured the issue may come from my connectionString :

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CRA2.csdl|res://*/Models.CRA2.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRA2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008;initial catalog=CRAV34;persist security info=True;user id=sa;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

All the changes I have done by switching to EF6 might have caused a problem and I can't figure out why.

EDIT :

After following Guruprasad Rao guidelines, I have added back the EF string and the default one giving me the following :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CRAV34Entities3" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CRA2.csdl|
                                res://*/Models.CRA2.ssdl|
                                res://*/Models.CRA2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                                provider connection string=&quot;data source=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008;
                                                                 initial catalog=CRAV34;
                                                                 persist security info=True;
                                                                 user id=sa;
                                                                 multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                                                                 application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />


<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="packet size=4096;Data Source=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=CRAV34;User ID=sa;Password=as0;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Which gives me the error

> The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized.

It appears that it happens here :

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` be `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`?

Comment: It then gives me the following error : "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.". I guess the format is wrong

Comment: See **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14473184/2065039)**.. Try changing your `application name` in connection string to `App`

Comment: Done, I have added more information